# Equation of plane passing through 3 points

Tags: geometry

Given three points $a, b, c\in \mathbb R^3$, how do we find the equation of the plane passing through these three points?

*Original Question : Let $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a twice differentiable parametric curve, which is nowhere straight. For arbitrary h find the equation of the plane that goes through the three points $p(t)$, $p(t+h)$, $p(t−h)$. Then find the equation of the limit plane that one obtains from letting $h\to 0$. Verify that the tangent and normal unit vectors at $p(t)$ lie on that plane.
I just want to know how to form the equation of the plane using the three coordinates provided. (Please no complete answer to the above question.)*

Comment: Nice question, +1.  I added the "differential geometry" tag.

Comment: @RobertLewis is the answer $$r=a+(b-a)t+(c-a)s$$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Sorry that I made another changes to the question and took away the tag. The first version is just too misleading, the OP does not want ppl to solve that DG question....

Comment: @FaiqRaees Have you tried searching for "equation of plane passing through 3 points"?  Are you looking for an implicit equation? A parameterization?

Comment: @KyleMiller please look at the previous edited version of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametric equation of the plane passing through the three points $p(t)$, $p(t+h)$, $p(t−h)$ is 
$$Q_{t,h}(r,s):=p(t)+\frac{p(t+h)-p(t)}{h}\cdot r+\frac{p(t-h)-p(t)}{-h}\cdot s$$

Comment: Can you please look at the previously edited version of the question? And respond in regards to that?

Comment: @Faiq Raees I have re-edited the question, otherwise it is hard to understand what' s going on.

Comment: Can you please tell why divide by h? Because I have learnt that if a,b,c are the vector points then the plane passing through them have the equation $$r=a+(b-a)s+(c-a)t$$

Comment: Because $r$ and $s$ are free parameters. Note that $Q_{t,h}(r,s):=p(t)+({p(t+h)-p(t)})\cdot r+({p(t-h)-p(t)})\cdot s$ is another parametric equation of the same plane.

Comment: Can you answer one last question? Is dividing by h essential to solve this question? Is it done to calculate the limit plane? On that note, can you clearing what a limit plane is?

Comment: @FaiqRaees It is done to calculate the limit plane. Do you know the term "osculanting"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_plane

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66320/discussion-between-faiq-raees-and-robert-z).

Answer (score 1):

First, assume that the 3 points are not co-linear. The normal to the plane is then nontrivial:
$\mathbf n = (\mathbf b - \mathbf a) \times (\mathbf c - \mathbf a)$.

Let $\mathbf r$ be a point on the plane. The equation of the plane is:

$$
(\mathbf r - \mathbf a)\cdot \mathbf n = 0,
$$

or explicitly:

$$
(\mathbf r - \mathbf a)\cdot \big( \mathbf (\mathbf b - \mathbf a) \times (\mathbf c - \mathbf a) \big)= 0.
$$

Intuition: $(\mathbf r - \mathbf a)$ is a vector parallel to the plane, thus its dot product with the plane's normal has to vanish.

Comment: I did not see the original question, so my answer is to the general question